# How can i jump to next page in Scrapy Rules

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I have set Rules to get the next pages from the start_url, but it's not working, it only crawls the start_urls page, and the links in that page (with parseLinks). It doesn't go to the next page set in Rules.

any help ?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import log
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testes2'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/pesquisa/filtro/?tipo=0&local=0'
]

rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="seguinte"]/@href')), follow=True),)

def parse(self, response):
     sel = Selector(response)
     urls = sel.xpath('//div[@id="btReserve"]/../@href').extract()
     for url in urls:
        url = urljoin(response.url, url)
        self.log('URLS: %s' % url)
        yield Request(url, callback = self.parseLinks)

def parseLinks(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    titulo = sel.xpath('h1/text()').extract()
    morada = sel.xpath('//div[@class="MORADA"]/text()').extract()
    email = sel.xpath('//a[@class="sendMail"][1]/text()')[0].extract()
    url = sel.xpath('//div[@class="contentContacto sendUrl"]/a/text()').extract()
    telefone = sel.xpath('//div[@class="telefone"]/div[@class="contentContacto"]/text()').extract()
    fax = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fax"]/div[@class="contentContacto"]/text()').extract()
    descricao = sel.xpath('//div[@id="tbDescricao"]/p/text()').extract()
    gps = sel.xpath('//td[@class="sendGps"]/@style').extract()

    print titulo, email, morada
```

Comment: Check this answer , this will solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227546/scrapy-crawls-first-page-but-does-not-follow-links?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not override the `parse` method from `CrawlSpider`, otherwise the `Rule`s will not be followed.

See the warning at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

Comment: I've changed parse to parsePage, and set Rule callback to callback='parsePage' and know it doesnt enter in the def parsePage

Comment: Try using `restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="seguinte"]')), callback='parsePage', follow=True),)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spider Class flow:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider): is not the proper class
    instead of this use : class MySpider(Spider)
name = 'testes2'
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = [
'http://www.example.com/pesquisa/filtro/?tipo=0&local=0'
]

In Spider Class you do not need rules. So discard it.
"Not Usable in Spider Class" rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="seguinte"]/@href')), follow=True),)
```